# Почему не работает highlight.js?

Tags: javascript

Но почему то `span` тег не подсвечивается, его даже не видно, только текст который в нем. То есть он использовался, как тег. Но разве не фишка этой библиотеки в том, чтобы экранировать теги и подсвечивать их?

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/default.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="jQuey.js"></script>
    <script src="highlight.pack.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

   <code class="lang-html html">
     <span>Hello World</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

### UPD

1) Для того, что бы теги отображались в браузере как текст, а не обрабатывались нужно экранировать(заменить) на специальные символы. Попробуйте так:

```
<pre>
    <code class="html">
        &lt;span&gt;Hello World&lt;/span&gt;
    </code>
</pre>
```

Если вы используете `PHP` то вам поможет функция [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

И еще есть демо на офф. сайте – https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/

2) В [документации](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) явно написанно, что надо вызвать метод:

> The bare minimum for using highlight.js on a web page is linking to the library along with one of the styles and calling initHighlightingOnLoad

Вам нужно добавить строку в `HTML`:

```
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

Или вариант из той же документации, после загрузки всей страницы:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

3) Лучше всегда писать абсолютные линки

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/default.css" type="text/css">
<script src="/jQuey.js"></script>
<script src="/highlight.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: добавил, забыл просто указать это в коде

Comment: @KristoferStrong обновил ответ